# Is it necessary to report model fit indices for no latent variable model?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I built a moderated mediation model (Hayes Model 8 with no latent variables) for my research. Is it necessary to report model fit indices (e.g., CFI, Chi-squares) for this kind of research model?

If yes, what's the Lavaan syntax for this type of model (Hayes Model 8)?

Comment: I followed the instruction from this link https://ademos.people.uic.edu/Chapter15.html#5_moderated_mediation_analyses_using_%E2%80%9Clavaan%E2%80%9D_package and was able to create the same results for my model estimation as using Hayes Process R code. But the model fit indices were super bad. The Test statistic (Chi-square) was 120, and the Degrees of freedom is 2, making χ2/df = 60. How do I interpret these data?

Answer (score 1):

Whether a model has latent variables is not the issue. One could argue that ain  regression model:

$y = b_1x_1 + e$

$e$ is a latent variable - it's not directly measured.

If the model has non-zero degrees of freedom (and so probably non-zero chi-square) then yes, you should report df. Regression models have zero df, so the fit is not interesting - even if they have latent variables.

(Sorry, I'm not familiar with Hayes model 8).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do have a further question. I used 4 scales to measure 4 variables. Say scale A has 10 questions and 2 dimensions. And the same for scale B C D. In this case, when I try to measure the model fit, do I input the total score of each scale (i.e., 4 columns of data) into the model or the score of each question in 4 scales (i.e., 40 columns of data) or the score for each dimension in 4 scales (i.e., 8 columns of data)?

Comment: Depends on the model that you're fitting. Those are two different models, and each will have a model fit.